# Problem in visualizing folders in launcher

Tags: launcher

I have a problem with the display of folders within the **launcher** as they show up small as in this image. I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I use **large fonts** as an accessibility setting in order to display the text better. Can you help me? This problem doesn't happen all the time but every now and then when I open the application show, I think it's an operating system bug.
[screenshot of folder in launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Txpt.png)